# Windows Azure Mobile Services multiple inserts, how to get the scope identity

Tags: windows, azure

in the insert script of one of the tables using Windows Azure Mobile Services, I want to get the id of the just inserted and use it in to insert child related data in another table (one to many style)

any idea??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you also get the id of items that you insert within the server script:

```
    var theNewRow = {
        youProperty1: 'inserted',
        yourProperty2: 'in server script'
    };

    yourTable.insert(theNewRow, {
        success: function()
        {
            console.log('the row id' + theNewRow.id);
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
request.execute({
    success: function() {
        var id = item.id;
        console.log("The new item's id is: ", id);
        request.respond();
    }
});
```

}

Comment: This is especially helpful when inserting custom SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Carlos covers working with 1:n relationships in this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/09/11/supporting-complex-types-in-azure-mobile-services-clients-implementing-1-n-table-relationships.aspx

As an aside, you can find a a collection of Mobile Services related posts here: aka.ms/CommonWAMS